# How do I set up live Twitch streaming from RetroArch on a Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, retropie, ffmpeg

I have been tinkering with Raspberry Pi's for a few years now and have some experience with installs, command line and using SSH, etc.

I currently have Pi 3 with Retropie 1.6.3 installed and I can SSH into the Pi from my Mac OSX Machine.

I have been searching the internet for about two months in regards to live streaming from RetroArch to Twitch natively (no capture card just the Pi and RetroPie with RetroArch).

I have had no success.

I have somehow managed to install FFMPEG (which most tutorials say to use for Twitch live streaming from RetroArch).

But when I try to configure the record/stream I cannot get this to work, (unable to select FFMPEG for RetroArch record driver).

I am going to be doing a fresh RetroPie Install before trying again.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

I need help getting FFMPEG or equivalent Recording for RetroArch and then be able to stream it directly to Twitch.

I want to be able to try this with lr-mgba, lr-gambette, lr-pcsx-rearmed, lr-snes9x2010 & lr-picodrive.

The following are some not all of the tutorials I have found but none have worked. In whole part or any combination. I have not even been able to record a video and save it to the Pi's micro SD card.

https://retroresolution.com/2016/07/06/recording-live-gameplay-in-retropies-retroarch-emulators-natively-on-the-raspberry-pi/

https://retropip.net/retropie/twitch-live-stream-from-retropie/

https://selsine.com/2016/10/16/how-to-live-stream-to-twitch-from-a-retropie/

If anyone can shed any light or point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

PS

Please don't complain or tell me about video stream quality issues, I really want to know if it can be done and see it in action even if it is a bit laggy and lumpy, seeing a £30 credit card size computer running a GBA for instance and streaming it to Twitch would be very impressive.

Comment: You are right that it would be impressive to see a Pi play games and stream simultaneously. Even if you got this to work it would put the Pi under a really serious load. I know you said the stream quality, e.t.c... wasn't important but I don't think the reality of this project is going to meet your expectations.

Comment: It really would be impressive. There are apparently some videos of streams from a pi via retroarch. However I am stuck at the ffmpeg fusion with retroarch, doesnt actually seem to do anything. I have installed ffmpeg. took some wonderful google-fu and a jessie backport repository.

Comment: @DarthVader I figured it out in the end and will post the link to the solution in my answer below. Also please take a quick peak at my two live streams on twitch these were both done via the pi 3 via retroarch one is gba and one is psx. I am very impressed with the stream quality

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this link](http://selsine.com/2016/10/15/how-to-record-a-game-play-video-from-a-retropie/) to the letter and even switched to the retro solution link for script of ffmpeg install (it is the bold underlined Retro Solution, also select all code from bottom of code to top of code easiest way of copying it). Essentially the steps were:

1. Updating RetroPie with `sudo ~/RetroPie-Setup/retropie_setup.sh`
2. Creating a script called `nano /home/pi/tools/ffmpeg-install.sh` with [this website's script](https://retroresolution.com/compiling-ffmpeg-from-source-code-all-in-one-script/) (which installs the prerequisite build tools, then X264 from `git://git.videolan.org/x264`, then fdk-aac from `https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/tarball/master`. It then installs `libmp3lame-dev` and `libopus-dev` from the package manager, then libvpx from `http://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webm/libvpx-1.5.0.tar.bz2`, and finally the FFmpeg suite from `http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2`)
3. Rebuilding RetroArch
4. Setting up a USB drive
5. Enabing recording

Then to be able to stream to Twitch, I used [this link](http://selsine.com/2016/10/16/how-to-live-stream-to-twitch-from-a-retropie/) and used appropriate emulator additions.

You can see an example of a successful broadcast on Twitch at [my stream](http://twitch.com/leopgiles).

One is GBA streamed to Twitch and the other is PSX streamed to Twitch. Each one says GBA/PSX test respectively.

This has all been done on an unclocked Pi 3.

I will be overclocking to test limits.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please *always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* Basically, if the links that you've provided go dead tomorrow, then your answer is of very limited use. Please improve it by providing at least a summary of the information the links contain which was necessary for you to solve this problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.